# ESXi switch issue with OPNSense

Tags: vmware-esxi, switch, vmware-vsphere, nic

I've got an issue with configuration of 6 port ESXi. I read [ESXI single vSwitch with 2 physical NICS](https://serverfault.com/questions/977186/esxi-single-vswitch-with-2-physical-nics) and that does not really resolve my issues. I just can't get this configuration below to work.

I've got a 6 NIC (WAN+LAN+4xOPT) ESXi
The NICs are connected as following:
[image]

- WAN: Modem
- LAN: Netgear 8 port unmanaged switch (with deviceA, DeviceB,
  DeviceC...)
- OPT1: DeviceX
- OPT2: DeviceY
- OPT3: DeviceZ

The ESXi config

[image]
[image]
Configuring WAN was straightforward but the LAN is giving me headache. I just want to have DeviceA..DeviceZ be able to communicate on the LAN-network of OPNSense, but all I see in ESXi are load-balancing options..

I configured OPNSense with a LAN and a WAN interface

- All physical NIC (without WAN) in one VSwitch, in one port group  and a VSwitch for the WAN, but no success. Whenever I connect an additional device to OPT1 then the whole devices locks and OPNSense / ESXi are unresponsive.
  [image]
  Am I missing something here?

Comment: You need to add more detail, show us ow the OPNSense ports are configured, a diagram helps a lot, even a screen-grab of the vSwitch diagram inside vCenter or on the Host Web UI would help. It also sounds like you have no port resilience at all, is that right? and it also sounds like you're treating the vSwitch kind of like a physical switch, which you can do certainly but it's not the typical behaviour. If the LAN and 3 x OPT ports are all in the same port group then they should all be able to communicate with each other.

Comment: @Chopper3, thanks. I've updated the post.